# Completing all sets in a weightlifting routine

Tags: weightlifting, workout-routines

I am 22 years old, and it has been 4 days since I started to train in a gym. My weight is  60-61 kg.

Currently, I am training on different gym equipment, but most important for me is weightlifting. When I workout, the sets typically have 8-8-8-7 repetitions.

My question is: **does it matter if I can't do 8 repetitions in all four sets?**

I am also working on pull-up, push-ups, legs exercises, biceps, and triceps.

Comment: If you are a complete newbie to weight training, I strongly suggest reading through the Strong Lifts material http://stronglifts.com/

Comment: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/4483/3778 is a question with some excellent answers on what to do as a beginner

Comment: @dato there is nothing magical about 8 reps. I'm not fully sure I understand your question but yes go ahead and take a look at stronglifts.com. Its one of many good beginner programs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important thing is progressive overload. So if for some reason you're doing the same weight that you did last time, and you're regressing in number of reps you can do in any of the sets, that's a bad thing (probably you're not taking enough time to rest, but also possibly that the load is actually too heavy for you). But on the other hand if you're increasing the weight gradually and one workout you do 8-8-8-4 and the next one you do 8-8-8-6 at the same weight, you're getting stronger and everything is fine.

Comment: what is enough time for rest  during weightlifting?i meant,if i do  weightlifting 8 times at first,how much time have to i rest?

Comment: @dato as long as is necessary to meet the targets you're setting, but I was actually thinking in terms of rest days. if you're working out every other day, and from one workout to the next you're doing worse, you should add at least another day of rest in between.