# Quick body development tricks

Tags: bodybuilding

I want to quickly get a good shape and muscles. I would prefer to spend 4 hours a day in Gym. I would like to take Eggs, Bacon, Beef, Mutton, Potatoes and Beer everyday with a hope I can achieve a quick result.

Will the above help me? or its useless? any other suggestions to quickly gain good personality?

Comment: This is vague--could you be more specific about your question?

Comment: See: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4483/absolute-beginner-in-weight-training

Comment: You want to be in the gym for 4 hours a day, drink beer and gain a good personality quickly?  Either this is poor translation, or a joke question.

Comment: Kerry, please edit and update your question to provide more details. Have a look at our [faq] and try searching the site to see if there is information that can already your question. If you question is fitting, that we can reopen it.

Answer (score 3):

- **Eat Big**: your body doesn't know the difference between protein/fat in bacon versus that in chicken, so there aren't any magic foods that will grow muscle (no, not even protein shakes). Eat enough to cover your ideal macro split (fat/protein/carb) plus an 300-500 kcal extra to fuel muscle growth.
- **Compound Workout**: don't start out doing the isolation split routines, those are really only effective for advanced bodybuilders. Do compound lifts such as squats, deadlifts, bench, etc. which will train and grow muscles in your whole body. Two good programs to follow are Starting Strength and Stronglifts.
- **Progressive Overload**: The key driver to creating muscle is lifting heavy. So always be lifting heavier when possible (sometimes, you will need to lower weight to ramp back up--that is okay).
- **KISS**: keep it simple and short. You don't need 4 hours a day to grow massive muscles; one hour a day is really all you need. If you're really wanting to spend time at the gym, do 1.5-2 hours max.
- **Rest**: Your body doesn't make muscles at the gym, it makes them in bed when you're resting. If you don't get a sufficient amount of sleep and wait a sufficient amount of time in between workouts, then your muscles won't fully recover and you will be inhibiting your own muscle growth.
- **Be Smart**: Avoid common pitfalls that stop workouts for long durations.  Learn good form to avoid injury. Don't be embarrassed at the gym when starting off at low weights / empty barbells; the alternative is lifting too much and hurting yourself. Stretch your muscles so they don't become overly tight and impair progress or promote bad-form.